# How to limit WordPress users from accessing other users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to limit certain users from seeing certain other users within the database.

We have a company that allows banks to register within their site with a membership. That company can then add their own employees into the site to access E-learnings, conference tickets, etc.

What I am trying to do is make it so that Company A can create/edit/delete their own employees, but they can't access or see the employees of Company B.

I found the following code, but I'm not the greatest in php and the person who posted the code on the wordpress.org blog stated it wasn't complete.

How can I make this do what I want?

```
// Custom User Roles to limit capabilities to view other users within other inst. 
function admin_users_filter( $query ){

    global $pagenow,$wp_query,$user_id;

    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='users.php' && !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        $editor_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $affiliate = get_user_meta($editor_user_id, 'affiliate', true);
        $query->search_term = $affiliate;
        global $wpdb;
        if (!is_null($query->search_term)) {
            $query->query_from .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON " . "{$wpdb->users}.ID={$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id AND " . "{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key='affiliate' AND "."{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value    LIKE '%{$query->search_term}%'";
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'admin_users_filter' );
```

Comment: You'll probably have better luck on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com, but first you should [take their tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour), find out [what you can ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and learn [how to ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My boss is my aunt and It is an internship. Please keep negative comments away. I'm seriously in need of help not for stuck up comments

Comment: I apologise if i insulted you (the personal connection was not apparent from your question), but i stand by the general thrust of my comment. This is a complicated task that is not suitable for an intern. If it is purely a training exercise, the fact you have resorted to copying chunks of code from the internet prove it is not teaching you anything. If its an actual client project, the risks (both financial and reputational) to your Aunts company, of delivering a buggy, potentially (extremely likely) insecure application are huge.

Comment: Purely just a training task. I have to write a report on why the code works the way it does so my next question would be how the code works. I understand partially how the above code works. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/ describes what the filter does - provides a way to alter the sql query wp uses to display a list of users. There is no suggestion this would prevent a user editing another user by simply guessing the user id and adding it to the query string.

Comment: So in theory I could have it auto-generate a user ID code that is different and out of order from the rest of the users so the possibilities of guessing it are limited? Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

> We have a company that allows banks to register within their site with
>   a membership....

If you're dealing with banking info (and not even financial data), employee data, course registration, tickets, etc., you're absolutely foolish to pull a random php function from the web and try to integrate it into a WordPress theme and expect the results to work and - most importantly - be secure. Even for use simply as a demo.

Do yourself and your work and your job a favor and fork out a little bit of money for one of many commercially available membership plugins for WordPress. They are reasonably secure, offer features you will find you need once you get into this, and offer support. Google or look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=membership